# Did conditions with click events work with negative statements?

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener, addeventlistener

I have an eventListener with a click event and want to trigger my function always but with two exceptions. This is my code (that works):

```js
function setCookieTrueOnClick (event) {
    if (event.target.pathname === '/info' || event.target.classList.contains('NoTrigger') ) {

    } else {
      triggerTheFunction('true');
    }
}
window.addEventListener("click", setCookieTrueOnClick, false);
```

The event triggers always but not when the user click the box that has "NoTrigger" class or when the user clicks on a link that goes to /info.

Now, on the other hand, when I use a negative condition the code doesn't work (it triggers the function all the time):

```js
function setCookieTrueOnClick (event) {
if (event.target.pathname !== '/info' || !event.target.classList.contains('NoTrigger') ) {
     triggerTheFunction('true');
 }
}
window.addEventListener("click", setCookieTrueOnClick, false);
```

I don't understand why, I also tried setting the eventListener with "true" argument, but it's always the same.

Comment: You need to replace `||` with `&&` as one of the condition is always evaluating to `true`

Comment: you mean in the second example? (the one with negative conditions)

Comment: Yes, in the second example.

Comment: oh I get it now. If I use || when I click the box with "noTrigger" class the other negative condition gets to be true because I'm not clickink the link towards '/info'.

Comment: Voila. There you go.

Comment: so negative conditions need to have && operators if concatenated, while the opposite happens to the affirmative conditions, right? They have to use || operator if I want to concatenated them. That makes sense, I wasn't paying attention to the operators! Thanks!!

Comment: Not always. It totally depends on the logic that you want to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Prerak Sola commented, you have reversed the conditional checks but not the condition as a whole.

```
if(!event.target.pathname === '/info' && !event.target.classList.contains('NoTrigger'))
```

You will need to also inverse the `||` into and `&&`
.Try it out and let us know

Comment: It works indeed, thanks! Sorry for the noob question, I wasn't reflecting about the operators.